# Connection string not found when trying to query database under SubSonic

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, subsonic, app-config

I get this error no matter what version of SubSonic I use. When I query the database for data, it errors out, saying it can not connect to the database.

However, it is able to generate the .cs classes(ActiveRecord, Context, etc) when told to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks folks...

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have your SubSonic generated classes in a separate project from where your main application is (in another project in the same solution).  Your main application project references the project containg the SubSonic generated classes.

If this is the case, your main application project must also contain the connection string in a config file, similarly to what your other project has.  You might also need to copy over some of the other SubSonic related items from your other project's config file as well.

Comment: I do in fact have a multi-project solution. I will test as soon as I can.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. I now know what I need to do. Thanks for your input. I do appreciate it!